# In shiny, how to have a new actionButton when a different variable is selected?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple task of printing the output of a call to `table()` on a selected variable.
I want to display the output when the button "Print" is clicked.

In the following example, once the button is clicked, the output is always triggered when I change the selected variable.
If I clicked "Print", and then change the selected variable, I want the ouput to be gone, waited to be printed again when clicking "Print".

Thank you!

**Here is a reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
data = iris

ui = fluidPage(
    uiOutput("selectvar"),
    actionButton("print", "Print"),
    verbatimTextOutput("info")
)

server = function(input, output, session)
{
    output$selectvar = renderUI({
        selectInput("selectedvar",
                    "Select variable",
                    choices = colnames(iris))
    })

    tab = reactive( table(data[[input$selectedvar]]) )

    observeEvent(input$print, {
        output$info = renderPrint( tab() ) 
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `output$info` is reactive to `tab()`, even while it is enclosed in an `observeEvent`. I think this app does what you want:

```
library(shiny)
data = iris

ui = fluidPage(
  uiOutput("selectvar"),
  actionButton("print", "Print"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")
)

server = function(input, output, session)
{
  output$selectvar = renderUI({
    selectInput("selectedvar",
                "Select variable",
                choices = colnames(iris))
  })

  tab <- reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(input$selectedvar, {
    tab(NULL)
  })
  observeEvent(input$print, {
    tab(table(data[[input$selectedvar]]))
  })

  output$info <- renderPrint({
    tab()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is it! I just tweaked your answer a little bit so that I get no output at all instead of a printed "NULL". I think putting `output$info = NULL` instead of `tab(NULL)` does what I want.

Comment: @cmasso6 I think you could add `req(tab())` in `output$info`.